# scroll smoothly sticky header on wordpress is not working

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, header

I am trying to scroll my header slowly and smoothly but it appears quickly.

This my [header](http://xoxostudio.xyz/pocketgems/about/) and this is [what I want](http://distribution.bonaverde.com/index.html) my header to be.

```
//Sticky menu after get riched bottom of the viewport
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var elementOffset = $(window).scrollTop();
    var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
    var elementHeight = $('#header').height();
    if (viewportHeight < elementOffset) {
        $('#header').addClass('header-sticky');
     } else if (elementOffset < $('#header').height()) {
       $('#header').removeClass('header-sticky');
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Give Transition property to `.header-sticky` class

```
.header-sticky{
transition : .5 ease top;
animation:slide-down 5s;
animation-delay:3s;
}
```

Comment: did. but no effect.

Comment: see updated code above. it is effective. @user3143998

Comment: added that. but still it show very fast. i want it to scroll down. slowly. please help. i will be very grateful.